# Энергия сигнала

Tags: python, массивы, matlab, anaconda, обработка-сигналов

Имеется сигнал, который передается по линии связи. Требуется наложить на него шум с энергией, равной энергии сигнала. Как найти энергию сигнала и сгенерировать шум с такой же энергией? Для решения использую python. Получается, требуется выполнить преобразование Фурье для сигнала, а затем...? Никакой код писать не нужно, лишь хочу получить объяснение в теории. Спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос, к сожалению, немного не по теме сообщества!

Comment: Комментарий действительно немного не по теме сообщества, я бы посоветовал вам перевести ваш вопрос на английский и написать его вот сюда https://dsp.stackexchange.com/